# Select largest 10 in a 200GB SQL server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am querying a **200GB** database in SQL server 2008. I have to work on this database on a daily basis for a long time.

One part of my work is doing the very basic statistics: find the largest 10 by some criteria. For example,

```
select ID, sum(value) val
from table
group by ID
order by val desc
```

I know `limit` is not available in sql server. So my (stupid) approach is to get all results and hand select the top 10 from sql server management studio.

This is really really really slow.

Can anyone provide a faster way to do this?

Comment: have a look at the TOP keyword in TSQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: just use TOP in your query. Speed is going to depend on your indexes.

Comment: `from **database**`?

Comment: Use Select top 10 ID, sum(value) as val from BLAH......

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
select top 10 ID, sum(value) val
from database
group by ID
order by sum(value) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with Sel1 as
(
select ID, sum(value) val
from database
group by ID
order by val desc
)
select top 10 *
from Sel1
```

Comment: Does the CTE provide an advantage?

Comment: IIRC, SQLS 2008 applies the order by after the TOP

Comment: No, there is no advantage to the CTE form, and in some cases there may be a slight performance hit.  ORDER BY is always applied before TOP is - you get the TOP N rows based on the ORDER BY criteria.

Comment: @LaughingVergil looks like I do not recall correctly XDDD

Comment: Oh, like THAT never happens. ;-) Been there, done that, misplaced the t-shirt.